# Python SyntaxError: f-string: unmatched '['

Tags: python, fastapi

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.params import Body

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/createposts")
def create_posts(payload: dict = Body(...)):
    print(payload)
    return {"new_post" : f"title {payload["title"]} content: {payload["content"]}"}
```

I'm trying to create an API with Fastapi, but every time I run the code I get this error related to the return statement: SyntaxError: f-string: unmatched '['

Thank you!

Comment: You could use `f'title ...'`. Just replace the double quotes with single at the start and end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please change

`return {"new_post" : f"title {payload["title"]} content: {payload["content"]}"}`

to

`return {"new_post" : f"title {payload['title']} content: {payload['content']}"}`

You can't have `"` quotes inside `f"..."`

The error says that after the first `[` the string stops and breaks.